# Expansion of env variables post build in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2

From the VueJS [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code)

> During build, process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET will be replaced by the corresponding value. In the case of VUE_APP_SECRET=secret, it will be replaced by "secret"

So if we were to look through the build files (post build), would we see the actual values for these env variables? I'm just trying to understand how sensitive env variables are kept hidden from the end user.

Comment: Yes, you will see the actual value rather than the name of the environment variable. There is no way to hide these values from the user - the idea of the environment variables is to exclude them from the version control. If you need these values to be inaccessible from the end user - then you should keep them on the server (backend) and do not include them in the client-side (frontend) JavaScript code.

Comment: So if I'm building a Vue app that talks directly to one of the APIs from Google, the API and other keys would need to be saved on the client side which would expose it to the world...?

Comment: @zer0kompression everything in client side is expose to the world. About APIs from Google, they validate it through the domain name you registered on their API service. So it doesn't matter if others will know the key.